# BDD en una API hecha con node.js y utilizando cucumber para pruebas automatizadas

Tags: nodejs

actualmente estoy estudiando BDD con cucumber, y quiero saber si el procedimiento que estoy hacienda es el correcto.

- Este es el archivo api.feature
  Feature: User service managment
  In order to manage the users
  As a developer
  I want to create a CRUD operations through REST API
- Scenario Outline: get user through the id
- Given A valid user Id
- When I send GET request to http://localhost:3000/api/gettingUser/id
- Then I get response status code should be 200
- And the user response body should contain user details

Examples:
| request
| {"id":2, "nombre":"roland", "apellidoPaterno":"Rios", "apellidoMaterno":"Campos", "edad":26, "email":"prueba@outlook.com"}

Y este es el api_steps.js

```
const {Given, When, Then, AfterAll, After} = require('cucumber')
const axios = require('axios')
const { expect } = require('chai')

let userId = 5;
let response; 


Given('A valid user Id',  () => {
    userId = 5;
  });

  When('I send GET request to http://localhost:3000/api/gettingUser/${user_id}', async function (userId) {
      const userID  = userId;
      const url = `http://localhost:3000/api/gettingUser/${userID}`
      response = await axios.get(url)
      return response
    });

    Then('I get response status code should be {int}', (statusCode) => {
           expect(response.status).to.equal(statusCode)
    });

Then('the user response body should contain user details',  () => {
              expect(response.data).to.have.property('name', 'Hyunna')
  });
```

Solamente me sale como
1 scenario (1 undefined)
4 steps (4 undefined)
0m00.002s (executing steps: 0m00.000s)

Conforme a lo que es configuracion y todo si me funciona.

Mas nose que debe de ir dentro de los gherkin en cuestion de Programacion para que las pruebas salgan las correctas.

Que estoy haciendo mal? me pudieran guiar?

Gracias!!!

muchas gracias por el apoyo

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la forma en la que debe de ir

```
const { Given, When, Then } = require('cucumber')
const axios = require('axios')
const { expect } = require('chai')

let userid = 2;
let response;

Given("a valid <userid>", async function () {
     return userid;
});

When("I send GET request to {string}", async function (arg1, docString) {
    const url = `http://localhost:3000/api/gettingUser/${userid}`
    response = await axios.get(url)

});

Then("the response body should contain user details", async function (docString) {
    console.log(docstring)
});
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).